# why is `exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270));` does nothing?

Tags: java, android, image, layout, camera

My app takes a photo in portrait.

In the gallery I see it OK

but when saved to my server i see it in landscape.

I have checked my image file and got

`ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90`

what does this mean?

I have tried to set it to `ORIENTATION_NORAML` but yet it saved in landscape only 
(whether taken in portrait or landscape)

```
      ExifInterface exif;
        try {
          exif = new ExifInterface(imageFilename);
          int orientation =
              exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
          exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
              String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270));
//also tried ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_UNDEFINED)
          exif.saveAttributes();
          orientation =
              exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
          boolean b = orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Basically some of device Image are taken portrait but result should come with landscape so in this case  ExifInterface is check image original orientation.

Comment: but it did. How can I rotate the bitmap and override existing file?

Comment: @Haresh but it have checked ExifInterface, and wanted to set it to a new value (`ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 or ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED`). why is my saving not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFromCameraOrGallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Camera"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGallery"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Gallery"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imgFromCameraOrGallery;
    private Button btnCamera;
    private Button btnGallery;

    private String imgPath;
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
    private File mFileTemp;
    public String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "temp_photo.jpg";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgFromCameraOrGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFromCameraOrGallery);
        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        }
        else {
            mFileTemp = new File(getFilesDir(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        }

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(getImageUri(getImagePath()));
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFileTemp);
                    copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rotateImage(mFileTemp);
            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                imgFromCameraOrGallery.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
            }
        }

    }

    private void rotateImage(final File file) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap b = decodeFileFromPath(file.getPath());
                try {
                    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file.getPath());
                    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            matrix.postRotate(90);
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            matrix.postRotate(180);
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            matrix.postRotate(270);
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FileOutputStream out1 = null;
                try {
                    if (mFileTemp.exists())
                        mFileTemp.delete();
                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                        mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
                    } else {
                        mFileTemp = new File(getFilesDir(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
                    }
                    out1 = new FileOutputStream(mFileTemp);
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        out1.close();
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {

                    }
                }
                imgFromCameraOrGallery.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileTemp.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        });

    }

    private Bitmap decodeFileFromPath(String path){
        Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            int inSampleSize = 1024;
            if (o.outHeight > inSampleSize || o.outWidth > inSampleSize) {
                scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(inSampleSize / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
            in.close();

            return b;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
            final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            final String imageOrderBy = null;
            Uri tempUri = getUri();
            Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(tempUri, imageColumns,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "="+id, null, imageOrderBy);
            if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }

    }

    private Uri getUri() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    private Uri getImageUri(String path) {
        return Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    }

    public void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain? how come my code doesn't work? what should your code fix?

Comment: rotateImage seems like a wacky thing to be running on the UI thread no?

Comment: @Elad - basically the solution shown here is to read the EXIF data and to rotate and create a bitmap in the proper orientation.  That way, your server won't see the incorrect EXIF and will display it correctly.